# Vue did not read my child component in v-for loops

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

**What's wrong:** Vue returns an empty array on when I *console.log* it. However when I clicked it in Developer Tools, the data was there!

**Background story:** I was actually trying to make a total value of child's data wheter child has this value or not, however upon trying to just opening the component data none showed up!

**P.S.** The child data will automatically updated every X seconds.

The result of `console.log(this.$children);` shows `[]` (empty array) in console. But when I clicked it, it opens the whole children array. But when I tried to reveal it via `this.$children[0]`, it shows value of `undefined`!

So here's my link to JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/irfandyjip89/zmn5yhju/

```js
Vue.component("comp", {
  props: ["location"],
  template: "#comp"
})
vm = new Vue({
  el: "#vm",
  data: {
    location: [{
      nation: "America",
      money: "Dollar"
    }, {
      nation: "China",
      money: "Yuan"
    }, {
      nation: "Thailand",
      language: "Baht"
    }]
  },
  computed: {
    totalNation() {
      console.log(this.$children)
      return this.location.length
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<section id="vm">
  Total of Nations : {{totalNation}}
  <comp v-for="loc in location" :location="loc.nation"></comp>
  Child : {{$children}}
</section>

<template id="comp">
    <li>{{location}}</li>  
</template>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.21/vue.min.js"></script>
```

**What should happen:**
I can access children's data.

Please feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: Read [vm-children](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-children). Note there’s no order guarantee for $children, and it is not reactive.

Comment: Ah.. I see.. are there any work around to access children data? Do I have to use $emit instead?

Comment: Yes, $emit or a storage library, like Vuex. But in this case, $emit is enough.